# Не запускается скомпиленный jar IDEA

Tags: java, jar, компилятор, build

Пользуюсь IDEA. Приложение Swing. Создал артефакт. Указал `Main-Class` - MANIFEST создал в корне `src\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF`

Содержимое:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.Main
```

В скомпиленном `jar` манифест находится по пути `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`.

Пробовал через CMD - все запускается. Но мне нужно что бы по jar-у открывалось.

В чем проблема?

Comment: Приложение консольное?
Если да, то оно не будет запускаться не через командную строку.

Comment: @K.Zakhar нет. Swing приложение

Comment: @Tsyklop У тебя он и не должен был открываться по двойному клику, если хочешь чтобы запускался, можешь написать батник или скрипт для запуска, ну или к примеру в exe завернуть.

Comment: @ElmoKennedy нет. это не так. я делал запускаемый jar файл таким образом. но почему-то сейчас работать не хочет.

Comment: Возможно у вас в системе расширение `*.jar` не привязано к `javaw.exe`. В свойствах файла укажите чем следует запускать этот файл.

Comment: Можно как написано выше в комментарии привязать расширение, чтобы приложение выполнялось по двойному клику, а можно восользоваться, например, Launch4J (http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) и сгенерить EXE-файл.

Comment: Tsyklop, имеется та же самая проблема. Заметил, что после того как добавил новый библиотеки, в манифесте код из библиотек, а не из основного манифеста. Вот я его вручную туда копировал и всё норм. А иногда по 10 раз копировал, пытался выискивать всякие лишние пробелы, по новой создавал сборку и в итоге запускалось. Сейчас вот минут 30 пробую никак не запускается)

Comment: Bleser, иногда jar запускается, а иногда нет. значит проблема не в привязке. Всё дело в манифесте я думаю. Насчет exe понятное дело, но если человеку не нужен exe, а нужен исполняемый jar ?

Comment: Кстати в данном случае у меня не запускается из-за того что путь на драйвер в ресурсах я указал кажется неверно . Чтобы увидеть это исключение надо запустить jar в командной строке. Становитесь в командной строке в директорию , где лежит jar . И пишите java -jar name.jar  и вы увидите исключение